# Android Multi-Part sms content becomes unreadable on reception

Tags: android, sms, multipart

I am working on an android project, that deals with device authentication via sms.
The problem I am facing is, when the authentication key is being sent, the receiving device gets a garbled text and not the original sent content.

I am using two instances of the emulator to test the code.

Here is the relevant code :

```
String MyPublic = "__key("+N.toString()+")yek__";
ArrayList<String> parts = smsmgr.divideMessage(MyPublic);
smsmgr.sendMultipartTextMessage(senderNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

How ever when I am sending a single sms within 160 characters, then this problem isn't disappears.

Here is the code I am using to listen for incoming messages.

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            msgReceived = false;
            Object[] pdus=(Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");

                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                }
                SmsMessage sms = messages[0];
                String body;
                if (messages.length == 1 || sms.isReplace()) {
                    body = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();
                } else {
                    StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                    }
                    body = bodyText.toString();
                }
}
```

The message that is received when the 'Multi-part' thing is used is of this type : 
[image]

The "HelloWorld" was sent as a single-part message(Non-Multipart) and the 3rd and second from below are parts of that multipart authentication key.

Need Help resolving this.

Regards
Priyabrata.

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: I just found that, this issue occurs mostly only on emulators, not on real devices. Reference : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13737

Comment: I've not. I tried it on my android mobile and seem'd to have the same problem.