# Creating table dynamically (On Button Click) In Android

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic

I am writing an application and it needs tables to be created dynamically.
I've written the following code :

```
public void CreateDynamicTables(String Table_Name, String Contact_ID, String Display_Name){
        dbs.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + "(" + CID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + DName + " TEXT);";
        dbs.execSQL(query);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CID, Contact_ID);
        cv.put(DName, Display_Name);
        db.insert(Table_Name, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
```

But it crashes the application. Cannot find whats wrong with it.

Logcat:

[image: Logcat]

Comment: can you provide the LogCat Error

Comment: added logcat to the main thread ^^

Comment: line 62 : dbs.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);

Comment: Did you initialize dbs anywhere? It's not in the code provided...

Comment: Nope, that led to the problem. Now it works.

Comment: Anyway, Can I mark both answers as correct ?? As both are correct and thank you to both of you for helping me out.

Comment: You can mark only one. I suggest you choose @MDMalik, because he noticed that before my answer.

Comment: @Melquiades Thanks for the suggestion, Priaybrata it was a pleasure... Next Question ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574582/android-multi-part-sms-content-becomes-unreadable-on-reception @MDMalik ;)

Comment: @MDMalik i am also stuck in such situation, I have a chat app and i want to store the chat msgs. like whatsapp does. How can i achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some places you were using `db` at some places `dbs`

Try this code

```
public void CreateDynamicTables(String Table_Name, String Contact_ID, String Display_Name)       
{

       dbs = this.getWritableDatabase();
        dbs.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + "(" + CID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + DName + " TEXT);";
        dbs.execSQL(query);
        dbs = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CID, Contact_ID);
        cv.put(DName, Display_Name);
        dbs.insert(Table_Name, null, cv);
        dbs.close();
    }
```

Comment: I used dbs(global variable) to to create the table and db(local) to insert data in the table. However, changing db to dbs, didn't help and results in the same error.

Comment: @Priyabrata try Log.i and find till which step does it executes.. Will be easier to help you out

Comment: It executes the first line and crashes. i.e DROP TABLE IF EXISTS line

Comment: do u have this code `dbs = this.getWritableDatabase();`

Answer (score 2):

If **NullPointerException** happens - as you say - on line:

```
dbs.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
```

then most likely your **dbs** is not initialized. Initialize it before using with:

```
dbs = getWritableDatabase();
```

Also, check if Table_Name is not null too.

Comment: Spot on!! That Worked!!